# Corona - first line of hello world sample produces unexpected result

Tags: coronasdk

Just sitting down to learn the CoronaSDK from scratch, and I just started working through the Hello World sample app in the documentation.  The very first line of code I executed produces unexpected results, and I was unable to find this issue discussed elsewhere.

myTextObject = display.newText("Hello World!",50,50,"Arial",60)

According to the documentation, this is supposed to display the text on the screen starting 50 pixels from the left and 50 pixels from the top.  In every virtual device I try in the emulator, the text starts to the left of the edge of the screen.  I had to change the coordinates to 170,50 to get the text to show at the top left (with no, or very little, padding).

I'm on simulator version 2013.2076

Do I have something setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself.  The documentation hasn't been completely updated to reflect API changes in Corona's graphics engine.

rather than left/top coordinates, the values now indicate where the center of the object should be located, so this works better:
display.newText("Hello World!",display.contentCenterX,50,"Arial",60)

If you found this because you're also having problems with the hello world tutorial, note also that color RGB values are no longer 0-255 but 0-1.